# How to send and extract class

Tags: php, class

I need to send and get Class into another class like a variable in MVC method :

```
class Demo {

private $vars = array(); 

function set($var , $data) {
    $this->vars[$var] = $data;
}


function request() {

    extract($this->vars);

        var_dump($vars);

    }

}
```

And i want to use above class into this :

```
class Test extends foo {

    function __construct(){
        $this->demo = new Demo();
    }

   function register(){
        $user = Load::model('user');//Now User Is An Object
        $this->demo->set('user',"$user");//This Is Error
        $this->demo->request();
}
```

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class user could not be converted to string in

Comment: Is the ending `}` in the actual code for  class `Test`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove the quotes

```
$this->demo->set('user', $user);
```

And don't forget to create your variable in your class scope

```
class Test extends foo {
    public $demo;
```

should do the trick

Comment: Please put an explanation in favor of the action so that it will be useful for a general audience..

Answer (score -1):

```
 class Test extends foo {
       protected $demo; // you missed to declare this variable    

        function __construct(){
            $this->demo = new Demo();
        }

       function register() {
            $user = Load::model('user');//Now User Is An Object
            $this->demo->set('user', $user);
            $this->demo->request();
      }
}
```

Comment: Put an explanation please.